# Is it possible to share mixins across web components (and imports) in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, web-component

As a follow up to [How to extend multiple elements with Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157576/how-to-extend-multiple-elements-with-polymer) and [Polymer multiple inheritence/composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659670/polymer-multiple-inheritence-composition), based on their answers, I wonder if it's possible to share mixins across multiple  web components (and multiple imports) to reuse functionality.

Mixins seem to be the only way to share functionality across multiple custom elements. However, it seems like you can only use a mixin within one import. Which means, if you have a mixin, that gives a web component a specific functionality (let's say `draggable`), it's not possible to mix it into the construction of your Polymer element if it's not in the same import.

Maybe I got something wrong there but if not, it feels like that the use of mixins isn't very flexible either, because I'm still not able to share functionality across web components.

**UPDATE:**

As Scott Miles pointed in his comments out, it **is** possible to use mixins in more than one import. I just wasn't sure how to do that and it turns out, that it's very straight forward.

Let's say we have a mixin that should be shared across multiple components, but components are  distributed over many imports. All one has to do is to define that mixin in its own import on the `window` object. So for example:

shared.html

```
<script>
  window.sharedMixin = {
    // shared functionality goes here
  };
</script>
```

And then, reusing that mixin in another component in another import, is as simple as importing  `shared.html`.

my-component.html

```
<link rel="import" href="path/to/shared.html">
```

From that point on, `sharedMixin` is available as global object within that import:

```
Polymer('my-component', Platform.mixin({
  // my-component logic
}, sharedMixin);
```

I hope that helps others. I'll write a blog post about that and will link it here.

**UPDATE 2**

I've written a blog post here: http://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/07/14/inheritance-and-composition-with-polymer/

Comment: Why not have each component declare a shared component Something like http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global. This is sort of what core-style does: https://github.com/Polymer/core-style/blob/master/core-style.html#L11

Comment: You're right, that would solve that issue. Didn't think about that `core-style` actually behaves exactly like that. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: This statement `you can only use a mixin within one import` is incorrect. Imports are not automatically scoped.

Comment: Hey Scott. Thank so what does that mean? How can I reuse these then?

Comment: You make your mixin once, and mix it in as many times as you like.

Comment: HTH http://jsbin.com/dirut/1/edit

Comment: Scott, thank you for taking the time and setting up this fiddle. Unfortunately, this fiddle doesn't cover how to reuse a mixin over cross imports. Let's say I have two imports that both have a custom element each. Also, both should share functionality through a mixin. Declaring the mixin in one import makes it unavailable in the other one, am I right?

Comment: I finally understood it. Updated the question accordingly. Thank you Scott.

Comment: You should totally move your response out to an answer & mark it answered - will help others skim!

Answer (score 1):

To use a global-like component is the recommended way to go.
make a `<name-you-like>` and use get/set to change it (also you can use attributes although they are only <strike>sad</strike> strings).

from [Polymer API guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global) you'll see working (good looking) examples like this:

```
 <polymer-element name="app-globals">
  <script>
  (function() {
    // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
    var firstName = 'John';
    var lastName = 'Smith';

    Polymer({
       ready: function() {
         // copy global values into instance properties
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
       }
    });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And play with them using javascript es5 getters/setters such as in the above mentioned case would look like

```
 <polymer-element name="app-globals">
  <script>
  (function() {
    // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
    var firstName = 'Arnold';
    var lastName = 'Schwarzenegger';

    Polymer({
       ready: function() {
         // copy global values into instance properties
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
       },
       get fullTerminatorName() {
         return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
       }
    });
  })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

[I'll be back.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgPePk3kGZk)

Comment: just an fyi, the `<script>` tag inside a Polymer element is already encapsulated, so top level variables won't leak to `window` and you don't need an IIFE wrapper

Comment: In this case, I think, since I wrote it on november, was to increase browser compatibility. If I recall correctly firefox was screwing with it at the time. But thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

This is now addressed by the [Behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) feature.

Example:

my-behavior.html:

```
<script>
  MyBehavior = {
    properties: {},
    listeners: [],
    _myPrivateMethod: function(){}
    // etc.
  };
</script>
```

my-element.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-behavior.html">

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    behaviors: [MyBehavior]
  });
</script>
```

my-other-element.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-behavior.html">

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-other-element',
    behaviors: [MyBehavior]
  });
</script>
```